# Spring Boot shows the String instead of the HTML file from an Angular2 Single Page app

Tags: java, html, angularjs, spring-boot, url-mapping

I'm trying to map all `GET` requests to unmapped url of the site to show the `index.html` file.

So, I created the following `@RestController`:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String redirectToIndex() {
    return "index.html";
}
```

My `index.html` is in `resources/static/index.html`. I also tried the following controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String redirectToIndex() {
    return "/static/index.html";
}
```

However, in both cases, browser literally shows the strings `index.html` and `/static/index.html` respectively instead of showing the html file. I tried a lot of different other approaches to similar questions here but can't get it to resolve... Please help.

EDIT:

My fill `@RequestController` class:

```
@RestController
public class FeedbackController {
    @Autowired
    private FeedbackService feedbackService;

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/feedback")
    public Feedback addFeedback(@RequestBody Feedback feedback) {
        return feedbackService.addFeedback(feedback);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String redirectToIndex() {
        return "index.html";
    }

}
```

My `pom.xml`:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Are you using jsps or Thymeleaf?

Comment: Angular for the html

Answer (score 3):

In your controller, change

@RestController

to

@Contoller

That will render thymeleaf page instead of rendering string as output.

Answer (score 2):

With @RestController annotation ResponseBody will be generated. In this case String will be generated as string instead of your view mapping.

In your case you will have to use @Controller and you will have to use redirect or create proper index.jsp and return "index"

Below is the code i can think of

add these into your application.properties

```
   spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/view/
   spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Add index.jsp under /main/webapp/WEB-INF/view folder.  for controller add the following code

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping("/index")
     public String index() {
        return "index"
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you give a an example?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Thymeleaf as the template resolver in your SpringBoot Project.

e.g:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

> then put your index.html inside src/main/resources/templates. This is where Thymeleaf looks for the static resources!

Your RestController should have the following

```
@Controller
public class FeedbackController {
@Autowired
private FeedbackService feedbackService;

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/feedback")
@ResponseBody
public Feedback addFeedback(@RequestBody Feedback feedback) {
    return feedbackService.addFeedback(feedback);
}

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String redirectToIndex() {
    return "index";
}

}
```

You may need to put your Security config correct to have this accessible.

Answer (score 1):

1. If your controller to return html then the Controller should have @Controller annotation and not @RestController
2. Also you should check the location where your htmls are place, if you are using thymeleaf template engine your html should be inside src/main/resources/templates folder.
   Doing the above two things should solve your issue.